# Get both name and value from option using Perl CGI param

Tags: html, perl, cgi

In my HTML code I have

```
<option name="PRODUCTS" value="3">Products</option>
```

I need get both the name and value values in my server side Perl function through my Perl CGI param.

I can only get the value, is there a way to get the name also?

Answer (score 4):

```
<option name="PRODUCTS" value="3">Products</option>
```

An `<option>` element does not have a `name` attribute, so this is invalid HTML and the browser will ignore it (except that it might make it available to JavaScript).

When the form is submitted, the browser will send to the server the **name of the select** coupled with the **value of the selected option**. This is the only information that the server will receive.

If you want to get 'PRODUCTS' then you will need to either:

1. Include it in the value: `value="3-PRODUCTS"` and then `my ($number, $word) = split '-', $value`
2. Look up the word that `3` is related to on the server (e.g. in a hash embedded in the script, or with a database query).

Answer (score 0):

`CGI::param()` with no parameters returns all the names.  Then `CGI::param($name)` will return all the values for a given name.

```
for my $name (CGI::param()) {
    for my $val (CGI::param($name)) {
        print "name: $name, value: $val\n";
    }
}
```

Update: sorry, misread "option" as "input".  option's name attribute isn't sent to the server at all, so there's no way to tell what it was without also having the html itself.  You could add javascript to set a hidden input field to the option's name when it's chosen, though.  What does populateCatArray do?

Comment: I may not have been clear. My HTML script has <select id="Category" name="Category" size=1 onChange="populateCatArray(this.value)"> before the <option>, so the $name in the CGI->param would be "Category". I need to retrieve both the name (PRODUCTS) and the value (3) with the CGI param call

Comment: populateCatArray is an ajax call to retreive data in JSON format which is used in jquery autocomplete script to populate a text box. I need the Name from option for a perl script which is invoked on submit

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Vars method if there is some doubts on what is getting passed, especially if you have thee same 'name' used multiple times or a js its producing elements that don't exist on the page normally.

```
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper
my $q = new CGI;
print
   $q->header({ type=>'text/plain' }),
   Dumper($q->Vars);
```