# Obtaining the text, not the value, from a select element with Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, drop-down-menu, cgi

Given an HTML form:

```
<select name="fruit">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Suppose the user chooses the second option and submits the form. In a Perl CGI application, I can get the chosen value, `2`, by calling `param('fruit')`. How do I get the chosen label, `Banana`?

I've been searching the web for an hour and can't find the answer.

Comment: Those are not called labels. They are the text nodes inside the `<option>` elements.

Comment: Related: [Get both name and value from option using Perl CGI param](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5307958)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it's nice that I get to the same conclusion as the answer six years ago. Should we close as a duplicate? I'm not sure because I give an alternative approach that the old answer didn't have.

Comment: Why not just change the value in the form to "Apple", "Banana", etc?

Comment: @simbabque I actually dup-hammered and immediately reopened because the other question asks about getting the `name` attribute instead of the text node. They're almost the same, but I don't think they're quite dups because of that one little difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. That information is not transmitted. The browser only puts  `fruit=1` into the HTTP request it creates. There is no way for your Perl program to have this information. It's simply not there.

Typically the Perl program would control what value means what in a situation like that. You would have a matching set up in your program that knows that `1` is *Apple* and `2` is *Banana*.

You have to change the `value` attributes. Maybe to something like `1|Banana`, to retain the `1` in case it is needed somewhere else. The pipe `|` in that case is arbitrary and I just picked it because your data does not seem to contain such a character.

If you cannot control the page, you could also make your Perl program fetch the same page that contains the form and parse it, to look up what the `1` means. That sounds very inefficient though. Look into [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) for a standard way of parsing HTML.

Comment: Or I'd suggest - if the relevant information is the fruit name, there's not really any need for the numeric value in the first place.